# postfix sendmail issue

Tags: postfix

I have postfix installed(should be default install).  I only set the relayhost to be the gateway I need to go through.  I then use sendmail as a test but the gateway rejects my message and I see that in my postfix logs.  The weird thing is in the logs the from email address is incorrect (probably my fault somehow but that is my question).

I have this file

```
 to: dean.hiller@yyyy.com
 from: dean.hiller@yyyy.com
 subject: hi there
 This is my body of the message
```

I then run sendmail with

```
 sendmail -t < email2
```

The postfix error is

> Jan  3 13:38:07 sdi-ci postfix/qmgr[1157]: 41B6BBF88C: from=, size=297, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
>   Jan  3 13:38:07 sdi-ci postfix/smtp[26034]: 41B6BBF88C: to=, relay=mailgate1.nrel.gov[192.666.555.555]:25, delay=590, delays=590/0.08/0.11/0.23, dsn=4.1.8, status=deferred (host mailgate1.nrel.gov[192.666.555.555] said: 450 4.1.8 : Sender address rejected: Domain not found (in reply to RCPT TO command))

EDIT: obviously yyyy.com is not my real domain and that is not my real ip.  That is never a good idea to post so I always modify it.  I fixed it by config in my below answer.

Comment: `192.666.555.555` ?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen http://www.notfake.com/not_at_all.jpg

Comment: edited the post for those were it was not obvious that yyyy.com and the ip are both fake.

Answer (score 1):

in /etc/postfix/main.cf, modifying mydomain and myorigin fixed the issue and setting mydomain to yyyy.com and myorigin to $mydomain fixed the issue.

```
mydomain = yyyy.com
myorigin = $mydomain
```

Dean

Answer (score 0):

Did you literally use `yyyy.com` as a sender domain? Your postfix is rejecting the message, because the domain of the sender cannot be resolved, which can be read in this log bit:

> Sender address rejected: Domain not found (in reply to RCPT TO command)

Other than that, did you alter the output of the log, because the resolved IP address of `mailgate1.nrel.gov` (192.666.555.555) is an invalid IPv4 address. IPv4 adresses can go no further than `255` per octet. So `666` and `555` are impossible values. It should resolve to `192.174.58.21`.

Those two things combined give a strong suspicion that your nameserver configuration is faulty. Make sure your `/etc/resolv.conf` file lists accessible nameservers to be used for domain name resolution.

Comment: all of those where fake as it is never a good practice to put your real ips and domain names out there.